# JavaScript calculate surface area

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code with JavaScript a function to calculate the surface area of a sphere.  The radius using a NumericUpDown.

I have tried to use what I did in a different assignment and it is not working like the other did. I am new at this and have not had any help.

```
function calcSurface() {
  var radius = document.getElementByID("radius").value;
  radius = math.abs(radius);
  Surface = 4*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius);
}
```

Comment: function calcSurface() { var radius= document.getElementByID("radius").value;  radius=math.abs(radius);     Surface= 4*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius);}

Comment: Please add this information to your question, not just as comment

Answer (score 0):

`Math.abs()` needs a capital M, and `getElementById()` needs a lower-case d. `Math.pow` takes two arguments, the base and the exponent, while you're only supplying one: the radius (which is the base).

Try this:

```
function calcSurface() {
    var radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
    radius = Math.abs(radius);
    var surface= 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function calculateSurface() {
    let radius = document.getElementById("radius").value;
    radius = Math.abs(radius);
    return 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
}
```

And if you have some div in your html like

```html
<div id='result'></div>
```

You can do this to get the result in your div

```
document.getElementById('result').innerText = calculateSurface();
```